# gwt- how to read a text file (Google App Engine servlet)?

Tags: gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc

I want my servlet (gwt Google App Engine) to read a text file located in the war/WEB-INF/ directory.
However,  when I run my app following error shows up:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /WEB-INF/lib/file.txt read)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)  **(...)**

According to [enter link description here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/kb/java.html#readfile) it should be possible to read a file via Filereader&BufferedReader

Did I miss something important? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: /WEB-INF is intended to be configuration data and other private data your server needs. Put files that your client will read in the top level /war folder, or a different subfolder.

Comment: mmmmh..You are right!!! I always get confused with that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/WEB-INF is intended to be configuration data and other private data your server needs. Put files that your client will read in the top level /war folder, or a different subfolder.